# Rails rolify gem /assosiation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rolify

I use rolify gem with devise for `AdminUser`

my `Roles` table

```
 class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:roles) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table(:admin_users_roles, :id => false) do |t|
      t.references :admin_user
      t.references :role
    end

    add_index(:roles, :name)
    add_index(:roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
    add_index(:admin_users_roles, [ :admin_user_id, :role_id ])
  end
end
```

model 'Role'

```
 class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :admin_users, :join_table => :admin_users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify
end
```

my issue is when i want to get users witch belong to role it  gives empty array instead  of my adminuser object

```
u = AdminUser.first
u.add_role(:admin)
```

`u.roles => #<Role id: 1, name: "admin", admin_user_id: 1, resource_id: nil, resource_type: nil, created_at: "2016-06-16 15:03:33", updated_at: "2016-06-17 09:04:30"`>

and when i do

```
Role.first=> #<Role id: 1, name: "admin", admin_user_id: 1, resource_id: nil, resource_type: nil, created_at: "2016-06-16 15:03:33", updated_at: "2016-06-17 09:29:32">
Role.first.admin_users => []
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a user has a global role:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :admin # sets a global role
user.has_role? :admin
=> true
```

Or to check at instance level In your case

```
u = AdminUser.first
u.add_role(:admin)

> Role.first=> #<Role id: 1, name: "admin", admin_user_id: 1,
> resource_id: nil, resource_type: nil, created_at: "2016-06-16
> 15:03:33", updated_at: "2016-06-17 09:29:32">
```

Instead of doing this => Role.first.admin_users => [] 
Try

```
u = AdminUser.first
u.roles
```

Rolify has a pretty clear documentation
[Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)

Comment: u did the same what i did. i want to get user from role,but no role from user

Answer (score 0):

oh i fixed it by changing relation in my `admin_user` model

from `has_many` to `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles`